# JSON Philosophy

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm in love and obsessed with JSON. I'm working with node.js and mongodb, and I'm torn between two different philosophies.

1

```
{
    "app":{
        "keys":{
            "facebook":{
                "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",
            },
            "twitter":{
                "apikey":"3241bly5vlv1l2hjv51",
                "sharedsecret":"gxdz1n25f1m235xm1235",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2

```
{
    "app":{
        "keys":{
            "facebook_apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
            "facebook_sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",
            "twitter_apikey":"3241bly5vlv1l2hjv51",
            "twitter_sharedsecret":"gxdz1n25f1m235xm1235",
        }
    }
}
```

3 or even

```
{
    "app":{
        "facebook_apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
        "facebook_sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",
        "twitter_apikey":"3241bly5vlv1l2hjv51",
        "twitter_sharedsecret":"gxdz1n25f1m235xm1235",
    }
}
```

To make the data even more complex

```
{
    "app":{
        "keys":{
            "facebook":{
                "production":{
                    "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                    "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",                  
                },
                "development":{
                    "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                    "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",                  
                },
            },
            "twitter":{
                "production":{
                    "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                    "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",                  
                },
                "development":{
                    "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                    "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",                  
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

alternatively

```
{
    "app":{
        "keys":{
            "production":{
                "facebook":{
                    "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                    "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",
                },
                "twitter":{
                    "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                    "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",
                },
            },
            "development":{
                "facebook":{
                    "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                    "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",
                },
                "twitter":{
                    "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                    "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",
                },
            },
        }
    }
}
```

How deep should you go? Is there a thing as too far in or to far out?

Comment: Matter of taste and practicability, I guess?

Comment: Vote for #1. Cleaner, more granular data.

Comment: These bring relational normalization to mind.  I wouldn't combine.  I'd also agree that going too deep doesn't make sense.  But it all depends on context.  Too deep or wide would make me start to think about whether it still makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with the following, and in fact did go with something very similar to the following:

```
{
    "app":{
        "production":{
            "facebook":{
                "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",
            },
            "twitter":{
                "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",
            },
        },
        "development":{
            "facebook":{
                "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",
            },
            "twitter":{
                "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",
            },
        }
    }
}
```

When I design a system I look for to create common code that handles multiple different situations.  This typically means creating a consistency in the design.

The above allows you to create a routine that finds the "app" and then choose an operating environment, either "production" or "development".  That can then be handed to another function and asked to find the specific service you care about, either "facebook", "twitter", or something new like "foursquare".  And then a single oAuth set of functions can handle the authorization process no matter the passed in object because it will consistently be able to ask for "apikey" and "sharesecret" without regard to which service is being used.

Speaking to the flexibility of Mongo or even Javascript... I love the flexibility.  It allows us to efficiently solve problems that would be more difficult in other toolsets.  However, that flexibility needs to be tempered with as much consistency as you can muster if you are going to get code efficiency and ease of debugging.

Comment: I went with this example before you posted this, which confirmed my reasoning. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that depends.

Semantically looking at that, #1 is more correct if you expect more apps to be added to that list. If app list is fixed (i.e. there will be always two), then #2 *might* be considered. But generally, you always use #1 since it's cleaner.

The above would be correct for, say, XML. As JSON is mostly about *serialization*, you choose one which is *easiest to use* for you. You will work on the data, and you know best whether you have problem with deeply-nested structures.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, you're facing the similar dilemma as all the developers, that try to design class design/XML design/SQL schema design do :)

From my experience, you should basically group:

- what makes sense for you
- what would be logical
- and would be easy extendable and maintainable.

What you should also keep in mind is:

- how you access/process the data and what is the behavior behind it.

I like to have things structured as much it makes sense to me, so I would the most probably go with the first approach.  However my experience is that the more I'm using the data, the more I see the way to optimize its structure. So I'd try to keep it ready for later refactoring. :)

Answer (score 1):

It may seem weird, but the point of is MongoDB that it allows you doing:

```
{
    "app":{
            "facebook":{
                "keys" : {
                    "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                    "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",
                }
            },
            "twitter":{
                "keys" : {
                    "apikey":"3241bly5vlv1l2hjv51",
                    "sharedsecret":"gxdz1n25f1m235xm1235",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why?

Well, the answer is the reason why NoSQL databases appeared at all: you're not sure about the data structure. Consider adding, e.g. `routes` field to `"facebook"`:

```
            "facebook":{
                "keys" : {
                    "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                    "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",
                },
                "routes" : {
                     "mainroute" : "00.00.server.xx1",
                     "subroute" : "00.01.server.yy2",
                }
            },
```

And that information has nothing to do with `twitter` because twitter does not support the hypothetical `routes` feature.

And what happens if you have the collection as proposed in #1?

```
{
    "app":{
        "keys":{
            "facebook":{
                "apikey":"1412v5l1v5jv5j1h2v5",
                "sharedsecret":"v5j12hv51hc4v123vmnv",
            },
            "twitter":{
                "apikey":"3241bly5vlv1l2hjv51",
                "sharedsecret":"gxdz1n25f1m235xm1235",
            }
        },

        "routes" : {
            "facebook" :    {
                "mainroute" : "00.00.server.xx1",
                "subroute" : "00.01.server.yy2",
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Looks a bit redundant, doesn't it?

Comment: So this allows `api.keys.facebook.apikey` and `api.facebook.apikey` to be the same?

Comment: Yes, but I guess you don't duplicating information that much. As the others said, it all depends on the case you are designing the data structure for. If for example the logic requires accessing the data **per application** then it would be wise to store the app info within one document (object, dictionary). On the other hand, if it is *production* / *development* keys you need to access - #1 makes perfect sense.